# Перевод вкладок на главной странице

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, конкурс

Наверное уже проблема известна, но как говорится лучше сказать лишний раз чем сидеть в неведении :) Вот собственное и виновник торжества:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я поискал в вопросах здесь и вроде такой проблемы никто не упоминал, либо я плохо искал :)

Comment: я в чатике писал =) https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51317839#51317839

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, чет я не успеваю за вами всеми :(

Comment: ну мой пост явно успешно проигнорирован, так что Ваши старания не напрасны

Comment: будем надеяться ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сейчас всё нормально:

> [image: Конкурсные]